Is there a flexible way to manage the \Alph command for counters (specifying the alphabet)?
I am asked to explain how to specify the concrete alphabet to output the value of a counter as a letter ( the \alph or \Alph command). I know only the default option, using the Latin alphabet. In my case, that is enough but people want to know the approach to use the other alphabets. Is there a way to switch the alphabet to print the value of a counter (using the default commands: \alph or \Alph)? Here is my sample below. We have a command to make examples, with an automatic numeration. Could you tell me what should I add to the code so that the numbers of examples would be from the specific alphabet?
\documentclass{article}
% can I include a package so that the command \Alph below would print not Latin letters as by default but letters from another alphabet (Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew or someone else)?

\begin{document}
\section{Examples}
Here are some examples below:
\newcounter{examplecounter}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexamplecounter}{\thesection.\Alph{examplecounter}}
\newcommand{\ex}{\par\noindent\refstepcounter{examplecounter}{\scshape\bfseries Example \textnumero\theexamplecounter.} }
\ex Let's see an example \ldots\label{ex1}
\ex Here's another one \ldots\label{ex2}
\ex And yet another \ldots\label{ex3}

There are references to examples \ref{ex1}--\ref{ex3}.

\section{Other examples}
Here are some other examples below:
\ex Let's see an example \ldots\label{ex4}
\ex Here's another one \ldots\label{ex5}
\ex And yet another \ldots\label{ex6}
\ex The last one \ldots\label{ex7}

There are references to examples \ref{ex4}--\ref{ex7}.
\end{document}


there probably is support from one of the language packages already but if not, it is easy to provide, Alph is a trivial definition \def\@Alph#1{%   \ifcase#1\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or    K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or     Y\or Z\else\@ctrerr\fi} so you can just make a similar \ifcase listing any alphabet that you choose

\alph and \Alph defines their list of alphabetic enumeration in \@alph and \@Alph (taken from latex.ltx):
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\def\@Alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or
   K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or
    Y\or Z\else\@ctrerr\fi}

Fundamentally, the functions take an argument (which is a counter) and returns a corresponding mapping based on the value of the counter. This mapping is defined using \ifcase, starting with 0: \ifcase #1 <0> \or <1> \or <2> \or <3> ... \else\@ctrerr\fi. An error issued of no match is found.
With this information, you can literally return whatever you want based on mapping. Here is a contrived example:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\mynum#1{\expandafter\@mynum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@mynum#1{% Counter representation
  \ifcase#1
  % <0>
  \or a% <1>
  \or B% <2>
  \or iii% <3>
  \or IV% <4>
  \or 5% <5>
  \or six% <6>
  \or Seven% <7>
  \or EIGHT% <8>
  \or \includegraphics[height=0.7\baselineskip,page=9]{example-image-letter-numbered}% <9>
  \else @ctrerr
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycnt}% Define new counter
\renewcommand{\themycnt}{\mynum{mycnt}}% Update counter representation to use \mynum/\@mynum

\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <1>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <2>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <3>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <4>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <5>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <6>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <7>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt\space % <8>
\stepcounter{mycnt}\themycnt       % <9>

\end{document}


I'm not sure what you want exactly, but babel provides a good deal of predefined counters and tools to define easily new ones. For example, if the main language is bulgarian, with the following preamble you get Cyrillic letters (with xetex or luatex; with pdftex the preamble is different):
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

Or do you mean counters in other scripts in an English document? For example, Thai letters (the font is FreeSerif because it contains the Thai script):
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[
  counters/thai = ก ข ค ง จ ฉ ช ซ ฌ ญ ฎ ฏ ฐ ฑ ฒ,
  Alph = thai]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}



It’s worth looking at the definition of \Alph which comes in two parts:
\NewDocumentCommand\Alph{m}{\expandafter \@Alph \csname c@#1\endcsname} % ①

\NewDocumentCommand\@Alph{m}{\ifcase #1\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else \@ctrerr \fi } % ②

The first definition ① is there to access the low-level counter macro (so that \Alph{foo} turns into \@Alph\c@foo). The second definition ② uses \ifcase…\fi to produce output for the numbers 1 through 26 (0 will give no output, if you wanted a zero value, you would put it before the first \or) and anything greater than 26 gives an error.
Note that the appearance of commands with @ in the names means that all of these definitions need to appear in a cls or sty file or be surrounded with \makeatletter…\makeatother.
This is the strategy for all the counter printing commands in LaTeX except for roman and arabic numerals which are handled by internal primitives.
If you wanted to do something similar, it would just be a matter of adapting the list in the second command, for example:
\NewDocumentCommand\Alf{m}{\expandafter \@alf \csname c@#1\endcsname} % ①

\NewDocumentCommand\@alf{m}{\ifcase #1\or $\alpha$\or $\beta$\or $\gamma$\or $\delta$\or $\epsilon$\or $\zeta$\or $\eta$\or $\theta$\or $\iota$\or $\kappa$\or $\lambda$\or $\mu$\or $\xi$\or $o$\or $\pi$\or $\rho$\or $\sigma$\or $\tau$\or $\upsilon$\or $\phi$\or $\chi$\or $\psi$\or $\omega$\else \@ctrerr \fi } % ②

